# How can I modify a page's HTML with AWS Cloudfront running a Lambda@Edge function?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm running a CloudFront distribution, which has a Lambda@Edge function running on it.

I'd like to manipulate the DOM of the page that CloudFront is in front of. Specific example: add a custom script to the page inside the `head`.

On *Cloudflare* this can be done easily in a worker (roughly equivalent product) using their [HTMLRewriter class](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/apis/html-rewriter/).

How can I do this on *AWS CloudFront*?

My working theory is:

- Observe the request for the HTML page
- Do some kind of manipulation of the body of the response - parse it into the DOM object and manipulate as needed

I haven't managed to get this working yet. Interested in other approaches or if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

**Do a `replace` on the body of the request where `uri === '/'`, to modify the string of HTML.**

I tried that and it works fine.

The request where `uri === '/'` should be the request for the HTML page.

So in my specific case, I simply did a `replace` on the `body` of that request (which is stringified HTML):

```
body.replace(
      `</head>`,
      `<script>
      console.log('my script')
      </script></head>`
    )
```

And this worked.

You could also bring in some kind of DOM-parsing library to do this kind of manipulation in a more elegant fashion.

Comment: You were able to get this to work for a response trigger? This says it's not possible: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-updating-http-responses.html

*When you’re working with the HTTP response, Lambda@Edge does not expose the body that is returned by the origin server to the origin-response trigger.*

How did you set this up?

Comment: @lou1989 can you provide a code snippet of a Lambda@Edge function?

Answer (score -3):

I've created a method to add GTM scripts inside `<header>` and `<body>`, using the @lou1989 response. [Here](https://carlin.ttoss.dev/docs/commands/deploy-static-app/#google-tag-manager) are the code and some explanation.

Comment: That link you provided is deal